# Дана вещественная матрица размерности (n x m). Вывести номера столбцов, содержащих только отрицательные элементы. Помогите понять, что не так

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

n = int(input("Введите количество строк: "))

m = int(input("Введите количество столбцов: "))

array = []

for i in range(n):

    array.append([])

    for j in range(m):

        array[i].append(randint(-9, 3))

for u in range(n):
    print(array[u])

temp = True

for x in range(m):

    for y in range(n):

        if array[y][x] >= 0:

            temp = False
            break
    if temp:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Это сайт для поиска помощи в решении проблем, а не место где все должны решить за вас.

Сначала присылаете попытки, которые предприняли, задаете четкий вопрос что у вас не получается, а потом уже вам помогают, что бы получить готовое решение - воспользуйтесь услугами фрилансеров

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: чем вас не устраивает приложеный код?

Comment: он неправильно работает

Answer (score 0):

вы не обнуляете  переменную `temp` в каждой новой итерации цикла `for x in range(m):`, поэтому даже если столбец подходит, он не выведется так как значение `temp` однажды изменилось на `False` и не обнулилось

Comment: Спасибо большое!